# MapControl for big floorplans

Tags: wpf, image

I trying to make an application where I want to display multiple floorplans with resolution up to 10000 x 10000 Pixel.
If I directly host the map on an imagecontrol I will need some time to load and consumes approx. 500MB.
On these maps I want to place up to 10000 Icons or Buttons (Doors, several electronic devices, etc.).
These items should show their states dynamically by changing color and text.
What is the best way to realize this?
I know that it could be done with Silverlight Deepzoom, but that seems to be obsolet. Could this be done with a maps api like bing maps api?

Best regards!

Comment: Showing the floor plan images could be done with a custom TileSource and/or MapTileLayer of e.g. the Bing Maps WPF control. However, that wouldn't help much with the dynamic elements, e.g. Icons, Buttons etc.

Comment: Yes. That's the problem. Bing maps also need a API Key. So it wouldn't work offline.

Comment: You could use a similar, but free control, like [this one](http://xamlmapcontrol.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks again for commenting my question. May I ask you if you are the creator of this Control. I ask because of the name. Anyway, I will give it a try and let you know if it works.

Comment: Yes I am, as you can see on my profile page.

Comment: I tried to find out how your Control works. I mean it's very well written but it seem to hard for me to understand. I will keep on trying. Do you have a hint for me how to avoid the infinite horizontal scrolling? P.S: Danke :-)

Comment: Not sure, but you may write your own Map class (i.e. a class derived from MapBase) to implement input event handling. Limit the allowed visible area in this implementation.

Comment: After one week of trying to do this without any countable success, I gave up and switched to Deepzoom for WPF. I have problems with that too, but it seems to be not so complicated. Thank you anyway.